# Filter data from Array which has one array inside

Tags: javascript

In my code i have array of objects.that array of objects should be filtered based on given input value. i have a input field to filter it. i am getting filtered value while consoling but it is not overwriting the existing values.
 this is the data structure i have. i have to filter with respect to name.
and the code which i wrote is given below.

```
this.customerDetails = [
        {
          date:'13',
           contacts:[
             {name:"Ashish", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
             {name:"Kevin", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
             {name:"Veena", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
             {name:"Pruthvi", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
             {name:"Rahul", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
           ]
         },
         {
           date:'22',
            contacts:[
              {name:"Jixon", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
              {name:"Hari", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
              {name:"Keerthi", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
              {name:"Roma", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
              {name:"Franko", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
            ]
          }
      ]

getInputItems(e: any){
    const val = e.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.customerDetails = this.customerDetails.map((item) => {
        const data=
        item.contacts.map((customerDetail)=>{
        return 
(!(customerDetail.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase())));
        })
        return {date: item.date, contacts: data}
      })
    }
  }
```

after filtering i am expecting result like this,

```
this.customerDetails = [
        {
          date:'13',
           contacts:[
             {name:"Ashish", time:"4:00 AM", guests:2},
           ]
         },
      ]
```

thank you.

Comment: Try `const data=item.contacts.filter` instead

Comment: already tried. i am getting while consoling but that value is not getting updated to the this.customerdetails. i am getting the original copy in this.customerdetails

Comment: Added an answer, that should show how you can use filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, you try to return multiple times and you can use filter instead of your second map:

```js
const customerDetails = [
    {
        date: '13',
        contacts: [
            { name: 'Ashish', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
            { name: 'Kevin', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
            { name: 'Veena', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
            { name: 'Pruthvi', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
            { name: 'Rahul', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
        ],
    },
    {
        date: '22',
        contacts: [
            { name: 'Jixon', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
            { name: 'Hari', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
            { name: 'Keerthi', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
            { name: 'Roma', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
            { name: 'Franko', time: '4:00 AM', guests: 2 },
        ],
    },
];

const getInputItems = (val) => {
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
        return customerDetails.map((item) => ({
          date: item.date,
          //filter out items that do not contain search value
          contacts:item.contacts.filter((customerDetail) => {
            return customerDetail.name.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
          })
        }))
        //filter out items that have no contacts
        .filter(
          (item)=>!!item.contacts.length
        )
    }
};

console.log(getInputItems('jix'));
```